# Docker Timeout error while starting Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

The hardware supports Virtualization and is enabled in the BIOS, and can be verified from the Task Manager.

I have enabled the Windows features for Containers, Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform.

Installed latest Docker Desktop version for Windows from https://www.docker.com/.

When I start Docker, it displays the "Starting the Docker Engine" message for some time and then displays this timeout error:

[image: Timeout Error]

I did `wsl --shutdown` and then restarted Docker. Still the same error.

Following is the output of docker version:

[image: Docker version]

If I run `com.docker.diagnose.exe check`, it shows a few checks as PASS and a few checks as FAIL.

Following is the 1st screen of the output:

[image: Diagnose result]

I tried reinstalling Docker, but it said everything is up to date.

How to make Docker Desktop for Windows work?

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, finally it worked after trying for several hours.

Here are the steps I did:

1. When I got the Timeout Error in Docker, I did not click Quit. I started PowerShell using Run as Administrator. navigated to `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources` folder, and ran: `.\com.docker.diagnose.exe check`

Towards the end of the output, there were a few suggestions, and I tried the following as per the suggestions:

2. `wsl --update`

This updated the WSL.

3. There was a command to synchronize the Linux timezone to the host system. I followed the command as suggested. (I do not remember the command now.)

Still when I ran Docker, I got the same timeout error. I again ran the `.\com.docker.diagnose.exe check` and it warned about a possible WSL file system corruption towards the very end, and suggested `wsl --shutdown`

4. I did `wsl --shutdown` as suggested, and restarted Docker.

This time it worked!